# Make collapsible toolbar automatically collapse/expand

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How to make a collapsible toolbar in android automatically collapse/expand when the vertical offset goes beyond a specific threshold?

As in, if the vertical offset is past the half-point of `getScrollRange()` then the collapsible toolbar should automatically expand, and below that threshold it should collapse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `snap` flag like below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
```

[Example Gif](https://i.imgur.com/9hnupWJ.png)

> Using this option will determine what to do when a view only has been partially reduced. If scrolling ends and the view size has been reduced to less than 50% of its original, then this view to return to its original size. If the size is greater than 50% of its sized, it will disappear completely.

You can read more about scrolling flags of CollapsingToolbarLayout here:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 2):

Just use **'snap'** option to get your desired output. Set **Collapsing Toolbar Layout** scroll flag as:

> `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"`

**snap:** This option will determine what to do when a view only has been partially reduced. If scrolling ends and the view size has been reduced to less than 50% of its original, then this view to return to its original size. If the size is greater than 50% of its sized, it will disappear completely.

**I hope this will help.**